# how to add grid lines in just one axis using a matplotlibrc file

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to define a style in a matplotlibrc file which only shows grids on the y axis. If I do the following

```
axis.grid: True
```

both, the x and y axis will have grid.Is there a way of doing something like:

```
axis.Yaxis: True
```

I did not find anything like that in the documentation.

I am using Python 3.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no rc parameter to change the grid on each axis individually. However you may turn only activate it for one specific axes

Options are to set the grid on globally and turn it off for the x axis

```
plt.rcParams["axes.grid"] =True
plt.rcParams["axes.grid.axis"] ="y"
```

or in the matplotlib rc file:

```
axes.grid.axis : y
axes.grid : True
```